# Latest jquery equivalent for file upload without refreshing the page

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, upload

I need to upload files without refreshing the page using jQuery.

I found the code using `jquery.min.js` and `jquery.form.js` in an old jQuery, but I need it to be done using the latest jQuery. Please tell me what the equivalent code using the latest jQuery would be for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#photoimg').change(function(){ 
        $("#preview").html('');
    $("#preview").html('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Uploading...."/>');
    $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
        target: '#preview'
    }).submit();

    });
}); 
</script>

<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>

<div id='preview'></div>
```

Comment: Include the latest jQuery and see if it works. If it doesn't, post the errors.

Comment: I am currently using jQuery 1.2.3 and it doesn't respond anything sir.

Comment: jQuery `1.7.1` was just released. Try using that ;)

Comment: I have already coded project with jQuery 1.2.3 so its difficult for me and there is no surety that 1.7.1 works with above code.

Comment: There is only one way to find out. Download the latest versions of both JS files and see what happens. I'm not sure what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was using old version of the jquery. Now i used the latest version of jquery and its working file. Thanks for all for support and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $('#photoimg').change(function(){ 
            $("#preview").html('');
            $("#preview").html('');
            $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
                target: '#preview',
                success: function() { 
                   $('#preview').fadeIn('slow'); 
                 } 
                };

            });
    });
```

Ref:http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#html

Comment: This code doesn't work with jQuery 1.2.3 . But only  works with jquery.min.js and jquery.form.js